# Difference between consistent and unbiased estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bias, estimators, consistency

I have a problem where I have to think of an example to explain a practical example of consistency and unbiased. The example I thought of is the sample mean.

Consistency is when the estimator (sample mean) reaches the population mean when the sample size becomes infinity.

Unbiasedness is when the estimator (sample mean) will on average equal to the population mean for any sample size.

Is my analogy correct here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be a random sample from some distribution $F_\theta$. An estimator $\hat\theta$ for $\theta$ is called *unbiased* if and only if the bias

$$b(\theta) = E_\theta(\hat\theta)-\theta,$$

equals 0, otherwise, it's called *biased*.

In many cases $b(\theta)$ is not exactly zero but it's a function of $n$ and s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty} b(\theta) = 0$. In this case, the estimator is called *asymptotically unbiased*.

On the other hand, an estimator is called *consistent* if it converges in probability to $\theta$. That is if, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P_\theta(|\hat\theta -\theta|<\epsilon) = 1.
$$

Consistency is related to unbiasedness, indeed, a necessary and sufficient condition for consistency is that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} b(\theta) = 0,\text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty}\text{var}_\theta(\hat\theta)=0.
$$

Comment: It's good not to forget about asymptotically unbiased.

Comment: On the difference between asymptotically unbiased and consistent, also  see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280684/intuitive-understanding-of-the-difference-between-consistent-and-asymptotically/

Comment: thanks for the pointer @Glen_b. Sadly that post was also closed as dup